# Reading data off SQL Rows sequentially

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on a process where I basically need to read a lot of customer data, apply some calculations and processes to the data and then save them elsewhere. I know how to do what I want to do, but what I don't know is how to read the data sequentially (row by row). Right now, I am reading the number of accounts so I can make a loop. Here's what I have:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
          conn.Open();
          SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Accounts WHERE ID = @ID AND Open = 1", conn);
          comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Session["ID"]);
          Int32 count = (Int32)comm.ExecuteScalar();
//testing purposes              
Label3.Text = count.ToString();

        int i = 0;
        while (i <= count)
        {
            //READ COMMAND HERE?


            i = i + 1;


        }



        if (i == count)
        {
           //loading bar
            UpdateProgress1.Visible = false;
        }
```

Now Inside the loop (I guess!) I need to execute a code to read data from each row where ID = @ID, read the data, use some processes (i know how to work them) and update the data (also know how to do this). I just need to be able to read the data and I don't know how. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: So are you going to have multiple accounts with the same ID? Otherwise I'm not sure how this code is ever going to return more than one row.

Comment: Yeah, there are multiple accounts with ID.

Comment: Then you should call that column something other than `ID` - which usually implies that it is a unique identifier.

Comment: I changed the name for reading purposes, the ID is actually a BranchID identifier since accounts come from different branches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of ExecuteScalar, you will want to use ExecuteReader.

Something like:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
      conn.Open();
      SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE ID = @ID AND Open = 1", conn);
      comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Session["ID"]);
      using(var dataReader = comm.ExecuteReader())
      {
          if(dataReader.HasRows)
           {
                while(dataReader.Read())
                {
                    var myRowColumn1 = dataReader["NameOfColumnInDataBase"].ToString();
                 }
           }
      }
```

Comment: You probably want to add an `ORDER BY` to ensure that "sequentially" means the same thing every time you run the code...

Comment: Alright will try this with the Order By suggestion but Aaron.

Comment: Getting this error: Non-invocable member 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.HasRows' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: Ah, I beleive it was the () after HasRows. Will check now.